# Combining Excel sheets/groups of columns by a condition in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Is there a way to combine 2 Excel sheets (or groups of columns inside one Excel sheet) so that the rows in one sheet/group append to the other sheet/group where so that certain columns values match.
To clarify:
Lets say I have 2 sheets - Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 has the columns A,B,C,D. Sheet2 has columns A,E,F,G. Column A in both sheets contains the same data but differently sorted (it is not sorted in conventional way (alphabetically or numerically)). I need to combine these 2 sheets into one, but they need to be combined so that the values in A column match (if possible the result should be ordered in the same way as the Sheet2).
Ideally, the functionality I'm looking for would need to be like SQL's INNER JOIN command.

I'm using Excel 2007.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you basically described the `VLOOKUP` function.

You have your two sheets, now you want to create a list, which extends A,B,C,D to A,B,C,D,E,F,G.

For that, you could just use

```
Sheet1!E1=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:G,5,FALSE)
Sheet1!F1=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:G,6,FALSE)
Sheet1!G1=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:G,7,FALSE)
```

If you need to create an extra sheet3 as a result, use this:

```
Sheet3!A1=Sheet1!A1
Sheet3!B1=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!A1,Sheet1!A:D,2,FALSE)
Sheet3!C1=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!A1,Sheet1!A:D,3,FALSE)
Sheet3!D1=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!A1,Sheet1!A:D,4,FALSE)
Sheet3!E1=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!A1,Sheet2!A:G,5,FALSE)
Sheet3!F1=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!A1,Sheet2!A:G,6,FALSE)
Sheet3!G1=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!A1,Sheet2!A:G,7,FALSE)
```

Hope this interpretation was correct.

*Edit:*

By the way, because Excel is not mainly intended to function as a database, this operation is a bit messy, because it does not dynamically scale. At least with the second approach, using a thrid sheet. You will have to copy down A1 at least that far, to match the last used row from Sheet1. And if you should copy it down further, so you won't have to worry about it for a while, you might need to error-proof against the empty cells.

Comment: I'm going with the first code you provided (I dont need a new sheet), but Excel throws me an error (the cell value becomes #REF). What is the reason for this error?

Comment: I am guessing, you might need to adapt the formula a bit to your situation. could you post what you are actually using as a formula? Are Sheet1 and Sheet2 valid worksheet names of your workbook?

Comment: I adjusted the formula to my situation.I have one Excel document that contains informations about customers. We need to send mail to these customers, and the company that handles the shipping needs addresses of the customers to sort the shipments by zone. To protect the privacy of our customers, I created a new document that contains only control number and the address of the customer. The shipping company returns that document (resorted) with 2 new columns. I need to append these columns to the existing document, so that the value of these 2 columns is appended to the proper customer.

Comment: OK, don't need your data - but the error you are getting point, that some of your references do not work properly. Therefore I asked to see just your actual adapted formula. In my example I used Sheet1 and Sheet2, if you have to merge between different Workbooks, you will have to extend with filenames. But you should be able to set up these formulas with the help of automatic selection from excel, just start writing `=VLOOKUP(` then select A1 of the Sheet1 from your example.